# Android Beacon - Beacon Values

Tags: android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

What should be the correct/optimum values to place for my beacons? The values I'm talking about would be the measured power, advertising rate and transmit power. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three of these values are dependent on your use case.  There is no one single optimum value:

- Transmit Power:  The higher you set this, the stronger your signal will be at a fixed distance, and the more accurate you will be able to get distance estimates due to a higher signal to noise ratio.  However, the higher you set this, the less long your batteries will last.  So if accurate distance estimates are more important to you, set this as high as your beacon model supports.  If long battery life is more important to you, set this to a lower value.  If you want a compromise between the two, set it to a value in the middle.
- Advertising Rate:  The higher you set this, the less variation or noise there will be in your distance estimates.  However, just like transmitter power, the higher you set this, the less long your batteries will last.  Again, if accurate distance estimates are more important to you, set this value as high as your beacon model supports.  If long battery life is more important to you, set this to a lower value.  If you want a compromise between the two, set it to a value in the middle.
- Measured Power:  This value must be set based on a calibration *after* you change the Transmitter Power value.  There is no tradeoff here.  Simply perform a calibration per your manufacturers instructions whenever you change the Transmitter Power.  You may also want to re-calibrate after you deploy your beacon in a specific location to account for transmission reflections and obstructions for distance estimates in the direction you most care about.